# how to find array max value when spliting

Tags: c#

hi I get values from a textbox and i split it to a array.. Then i got the max value it is not saying real value;

here code is used

```
 string[] cwatchers = textBox4.Text.Split('\n');
        string[] sss = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
        string[] emails = textBox2.Text.Split('\n');

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX");
        sb.AppendLine("SET !ERRORIGNORE YES");
        sb.AppendLine("SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 3");
        sb.AppendLine("SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 3");
        sb.AppendLine("SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 7");
        sb.AppendLine("SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST");

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt64(cwatchers.Max()); i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("TAB T=1").AppendLine("CLEAR");
            sb.AppendLine("URL GOTO=https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&lgout=");
            sb.AppendLine("WAIT SECONDS=1");
            sb.AppendLine("TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:SIGNINFORM ATTR=ID:SUBMIT");
            sb.AppendLine("SET !ENCRYPTION NO");
            sb.AppendLine("TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:SIGNINFORM ATTR=ID:PASS CONTENT=Maths7524");
            sb.Append("TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:SIGNINFORM ATTR=ID:USERID CONTENT=").AppendLine(emails[i]);
            sb.AppendLine("TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:SignInForm ATTR=ID:sgnBt");
            sb.AppendLine("WAIT SECONDS=7");
            foreach (string item in sss)
            {
                sb.Append("URL GOTO=www.ebay.com/itm/").AppendLine(item);
                sb.AppendLine("WAIT SECONDS=1").AppendLine("TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:watchLabel");
                sb.AppendLine("TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Watch").AppendLine("WAIT SECONDS=1").AppendLine();
            }
        }

        label5.Text = cwatchers.Max();
```

[image: here i use detaisl]

label5 says max value is 70

as we can see max value is 180.. could anybody tell me why this is getting false ?

Comment: are you trying to get the amount of elements in the array ?

Comment: yes i got to the array using split keyword

Comment: Most of the code is not related to the problem. Please provide a [MCVE] next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need first to cast the elements to `int`, because now they are strings. Try something like this:

```
label5.Text = cwatchers.Max(x=>int.Parse(x));
```

This parses all the elements to `int` and then finds the max value. Notice that it will throw an exception if any of the elements can't be parsed to `int`.

Answer (score 6):

*Literally* `70` *is* greater `180`, as both are strings. Having said this what happens is that every character in your string is compared to the matching character in the other string at the same position. As `"7"` surely is greater `"1"`, `"70"` also is greater then `"180"`.

To avoid a lexical compairsion use a **numerical** instead, you have to treat your data as **numbers**:

```
var max = label5.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
label5.Text = cwatchers.Select(Int32.Parse).Max().ToString();
```

You need to convert your `String` variables to `Int32` before performing a maximum detection. Otherwise the comparison will be performed on `String`, producing a completely different result.